# Code stops working about 1/5 the way on specific sets of data

Tags: java, loops, sorting, dataset

We had to write a sorting algorithm ourselves. I wrote one, it works for 20-5000 data sets of integer, finishes in about 4 milliseconds. However, when I moved on to the 25000 data set, it stopped working at numbers with value 804; I have been trying to figure out why for the past 2 days and have no luck, my teacher tried his hand at it for 5 minutes and gave up. Any ideas as to why it would just get stuck on an infinite loop on the same number would be very much appreciated!

Edit: Commented inner loop
Edit 2: Added full code

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class sort_old
{
static long steps=0;
static int nums, temp;
static int[] numbers, sorted, usedNum;
static String path="20_source.txt";
static Scanner scan;
static boolean used;

public static void main()
{
    try
    {
        scan = new Scanner(new File(path));
        while(scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            nums++;
            scan.nextInt();
        }
        numbers= new int[nums];
        sorted = new int[nums];
        usedNum = new int[nums];
        scan.close();

        scan = new Scanner (new File(path));
        try
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < nums; x++)
            {
                numbers[x]=scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {
        }
        scan.close();

        sortLargestToSmallest();
        System.out.println(checkResults(sorted,true));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sucks to suck");
    }
}

 private static void sortLargestToSmallest()
 {
int counter=nums-1; // mums is the number of numbers in the data set.
    for(int y = 0; y < nums; y ++)
    {
        temp = num[0]; //num[] is the array containing all the numbers
        used=false; //boolean to for checking if the number was used already
        for(int x = 0; x < nums; x ++)
        {
            if(temp<=num[x]) //finding the largest number
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) //only check up to the numbers already assigned
                {
                    if(usedNum[j]==x) //see if the number is already used. usedNum[] stores indexes of numbers already used; compare to current index 
                    {
                        used=true; //the number is already sorted, so it moves on to the next
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        used=false;
                    step++;
                }
                if(!used)//only if the number is not already sorted is it changed to temp
                {
                    temp=num[x];
                    usedNum[y]=x;
                }
            }
        }
        sorted[counter]=temp; //putting the sorted value into the sorted array
        counter--; // we were asked to sort from smallest to largest, but for some reason it didn't work.
    }    
  }
}
public static boolean checkResults (int[] theArray, boolean report)
 {
    System.out.println("Checking Validity");
    boolean stillValid = true;
    int counter = 0;
    while (stillValid && counter < theArray.length - 1)
    {
        if (theArray[counter] > theArray[counter + 1])
        {
            stillValid = false;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    if (report)
    {
        if (stillValid)
        {
            System.out.println("Checked " + theArray.length + " values. Sort is valid");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Checked " + theArray.length + " values. Found error at " + counter);
        }
    }

    return stillValid;
 }
}
```

Comment: what sorting algorithm is this? Also could you comment that inner for-loop, the one that uses j as an indexing variable. I'm having trouble figuring out what that does

Comment: Add some plugins to your browser for inspecting what are wrongs with your script. BTW,, what the type of sorting is that?

Comment: Hi, commenting it it rn. This is not a specific type, we had to make our own from scratch without prior information of what types of sorting are out there. But if i have to compare, i'd say its closest to selection sorting. Thanks!

Comment: If it works for 5000 and stops 1/5th through 25000 are you forgetting to initialize one array to the bigger size, somewhere? How have you determined that it's stuck in an infinite loop? Could it be hitting a worst-case sort situation and your browser (is it JavaScript?) is killing it after an execution timeout?

Comment: I know for a fact that the array size is big enough (it was declared in void main); this is blueJ, so just java not javascript. I'm pretty sure it's stuck in an infinite loop. When I tested it I made it print all the values as it is running that is sorted, and it just showed 804 for an hour (there isn't even that many values, and it's constantly refreshing new value)

Comment: It's my current thinking that the code you've posted cannot go into an infinite loop - three nested `for` loops with finishing tests referencing `y, nums, x, j` - none of which are set anywhere else in the code. The runtime characteristics are bad - a list of 100 items goes through the inner loop *0.5 million times*. 1000 items? *500 million times*. 10x the size of the list, program takes 1000x longer. But even so, if it does 2k items in 4mS, then 25k items would be a few seconds. Is this post definitely the broken code? Can you post the datasets somewhere (pastebin.com?) and the whole code?

Comment: Data set: http://pastebin.com/bXMHvTkY